# Elasticsearch ActiveModel integration

Tags: ruby, activerecord, elasticsearch, tire, activemodel

The [Tire gem](https://github.com/karmi/retire) has been retired and has been replaced by the new [elasticsearch gem](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby). The `elasticsearch` gem doesn't appear to include `ActiveModel` integration or `will_paginate` compatibility. Are there any gems out there that add this functionality on top of the functionality provided in the `elasticsearch` gem? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `elasticsearch-model` by the same author.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails) is what I want. Thanks to @RocketR.